# How to PREVENT ranking for a keyword?

Tags: seo, google, google-search-console, keywords, negative-seo

A client frequently receives unwanted traffic from Google. They do not wish to receive these visitors, mainly because they want not to deal with them through their support channels. So they asked for a way how **not to rank for specific keywords**.

What I am looking for is something like a personal blacklist for specific keywords. Maybe in Google Search Console? Or something like `<meta name="keyword-noindex">` :)

To my knowledge there simply is no such way. But just to sure, I'd like to ask you experts. :)

If there is indeed such a way, I would also like to know if there are possible unwanted side effects. For example, could it hurt unrelated rankings?

To be clear: I am already going to recommend improving title and description to improve the targeting. And obviously we'll make sure not to accidentally optimize for those keywords by making sure that they are wiped from the site. Due to some ambiguity this is not expected to be perfect, though. So to be thorough I am looking for more direct measures.

Comment: This can't be stopped. The best you can so is not do anything to optimize for those keywords and disavow any links that seem to help rank for them.

Answer (score 2):

For some reason Google thinks your client's website is a relevant website when someone searches for `bad-keyword`. This works in the exact same way as trying to score good for `keyword`, the websites content and titles and other SEO valuable items score high in relevance.

Apparently this site provides good results for this keyword, other than rewriting the content, there is no solution.

You can disavow links in Google's Webmaster Tools when they are indexed, but then you remove that page from the results completely.

Another method could be adding 'noindex' to the pages which have high relevance for the keyword, but this method isn't good for SEO either.

Comment: Also be aware that links, posts on other sites, and semantic topic (car versus automobile) can effect this.